# scala using string interpolation for string replacement

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation

scala 2.11.6

```
val fontColorMap = Map( "Good" -> "#FFA500", "Bad" -> "#0000FF")
val content = "Good or Bad?"
"(Bad|Good)".r.replaceFirstIn(content,s"""<font color="${fontColorMap("$1")}">$$1</font>""")
```

I want to replace the String using regex. In this case
$$1 can fetch the matched string, but I dont know how to do it in ${}.

plus. I know that scala will translate the interpolation
into something like this

```
new StringContext("""<font color=""",""">$$1</font>""").s(fontColorMap("$1"))
```

Thus it will fail.
But, is there any way I can handle this gracefully?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the version of `replaceAllIn` that takes a function:

```
"(Bad|Good)".r.replaceAllIn(content, m => 
  s"""<font color="${fontColorMap(m.matched)}">${m.matched}</font>"""
)
```

where `m` is of type `scala.util.matching.Regex.Match`.

There doesn't seem to be a version of `replaceFirstIn` that does the same thing though.

Comment: I think that is what OP means.

Comment: Yeah, I only want to replace the first one

Answer (score 0):

Seems is caused by `regex group variable` interpolation with `scala StringContext` interpolation has the different interpolation order.And `StringContext` need to evaluate firstly before go to the `regex` interpolation. Maybe we can try to get value firstly before `regex replace interpolation`, like:

```
"(Bad|Good)".r.findFirstIn(content).map(key => {
    val value = fontColorMap(key)
    content.replaceFirst(key, s"""<font color="$value">$key</font>""")
 }).get
 > <font color="#FFA500">Good</font> or Bad?
```